# How to call a string to a code of another element

Tags: vb.net

I'm having troubles with this code and I don't know the correct keywords to search about this topic. I'm sorry if the title isn't clear.

I am trying to create two different strings by using 'Dim' sentence and the calling it with a button but it isn't working.

```
Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        Dim text1 As String = "This is message number 1"
    End If

    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        Dim text2 As String = "This is message number 2"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    MsgBox(text1)
End Sub
```

It seems like the text1 and text2 strings are generated just to use on `Public Sub Form1_Load`, how can I use it on `Private Sub Button8_Click`?

Comment: See [Scope In Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the variables class-level members:

```
Private text1 As String
Private text2 As String

Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        text1 = "This is message number 1"
    End If

    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        text2 = "This is message number 2"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    MsgBox(text1)
End Sub
```

Often when passing values from one method to another, you would make them method parameters.  But in the case of event handlers, you're not directly invoking the handler method.  Since the handlers are responding to object-level events, in order to share information it should be stored in object-level state.

Comment: What about if I have not a string but I have something like: 'Dim setting As New Setting.IniFile' how could I call it from a different Private Sub like my problem?

Comment: Could you help me on that example?

Comment: @KING-MOD: Why would that be any different?  `String` is a type like any other.  Whatever type the variable needs to be, make it that type.  The access from other event handlers would be the same.

Comment: But if I insert 'Private setting As New' and then on another sub of code insert setting = Setting.IniFile it shows an error on 'Private setting As New' because needs something next to 'New'

Comment: @KING-MOD: Well, `Private setting As New` isn't a complete statement.  It's a new *what*?  You have to specify a type.  Any introductory VB tutorial will show that.

Comment: The code is this one: Dim setting As New Setting.IniFile("C:\settings.ini")

Comment: @KING-MOD: And what is the error?  What is `Setting.IniFile`?  (I'm not finding any classes like that on Google, is it something you wrote?)

Comment: It is imported from a Setting.dll file that I downloaded. The entire code is there: http://i.imgur.com/UG43mx6.png

Comment: @KING-MOD: And *what is the error*?  Please understand that this isn't a chatroom.  If you have a specific question, please ask it as a question and provide information about it.  If it's *different* from the original question asked above, you'll probably want to create an entirely new question instead of getting lost in a comment thread.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199289/call-two-different-files-by-using-the-same-name

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a private string variable in `Form1`:

```
Private Text As String = ""
```

Then in the event, change the value of `Text` accordingly.

```
Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
    Text = "This is message number 1"
End If

If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
    Text = "This is message number 2"
End If
End Sub
```

Finally in the button click,

```
Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
MsgBox(Text)
End Sub
```